# Extract values for multiple keys from list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, optimization, time-complexity

I am new to Python and looking for a little help. I have list of dictionary as follows:

```
data = [
    {'device_id': 'D11', 'ipv4': '1.1.1.1'},
    {'device_id': 'D42', 'ipv4': '1.1.1.2'},
    {'device_id': 'D32', 'hostname': 'MVPQ021'},
    {'device_id': 'D94', 'ipv6': '2001:0db8:0:7334'}
]
```

I need to fetch only list of IP address as follows:

```
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '2001:0db8:0:7334']
```

I have tried the following that gives me desired result:

```
result = []

    for x in data:
        if 'ipv4' in x.keys():
            result.append(x['ipv4'])
            continue
        if 'ipv6' in x.keys():
            result.append(x['ipv6'])
```

However, for a very long list e.g with 1000+ elements, this solution is not very efficient.

Is there any optimized way to filter out only the `ipv4` and `ipv6` values without iterating each element in a list?

Comment: For 1000+ ? How much ? It should a second to be done. I ran 10M in 4 sec

Comment: I'm suspecting that this loop is inside other loop(s)

Comment: stop use `x.keys()`, that is unnecessary and will slow you down slightly

Comment: Exactly how much `+` than 1000 are we talking about? unless executed on a potato pc this should be **very** large before one would notice a performance issue.

Comment: *Why* do you believe this solution is "not very efficient"? What is the performance you are seeing?

Comment: Also, probably not impacting performance, but use `if...elif` not `if.. continue...if...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well, it does calculate the same hash multiple times every iteration

Comment: @DeepSpace well, it's python. That's pretty marginal. *every time you use a global variable you calculate a hash* for example, or use an attribute... etc etc. If that's the sort of thing you are trying to optimize, CPython isn't the tool for you

Comment: In any case, I don't see a way to improve the *time complexity* here. Only micro-optimizations. In any case, you *certainly* can't avoid iterating every element in the list unless there is some pattern you aren't telling us

Comment: @SakshmKhare, in case you are using Python 3.8+. I have added an answer to take advantage of the walrus operator and use a list comprehension (no loops).

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf to be clear, there is still a *loop* in the sense that you have to visit every element. Also in the sense that list comprehensions are implemented as python-level for-loops with `list.append` at the end. They can be marginally faster because `list.append` is cached (you don't have to resolve the attribute `.append`) and there is I believe one small bytecode trick as well.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I agree with you that there is a loop involved, but it is also true that this solution is faster since it is not using `.append`.

Comment: Well, it *is* using `.append`. However, the method-resolution is cached. You can simulate this in your own loop by simply doing `result_append = result.append`. The bytecode trick isn't really achievable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3.8+, you can take advantage of the `:=` (walrus operator) as follows, and you can complete that in one list comprehension:

```
data = [
    {'device_id': 'D11', 'ipv4': '1.1.1.1'},
    {'device_id': 'D42', 'ipv4': '1.1.1.2'},
    {'device_id': 'D32', 'hostname': 'MVPQ021'},
    {'device_id': 'D94', 'ipv6': '2001:0db8:0:7334'}
]
result = [
    ip_address for e in data
    if (ip_address := e.get('ipv4') or e.get('ipv6')) is not None
]
```

Explanation:

1. For each dictionary in the list, you are trying to get the value for either key `'ipv4'` or `'ipv6'` and store it in `ip_address`.
2. If there is no value for both, it will skip that element.

Answer (score 0):

Change `x.keys()` to `x`, you'll gain about 20-30% regarding my tests.

```
for x in data:
    if 'ipv4' in x:
        result.append(x['ipv4'])
        continue
    if 'ipv6' in x:
        result.append(x['ipv6'])
```

Some perf for me

- 10M in 3.2sec
- 50M in 17sec

Comment: Didn't try, but I suspect using `map` and `itemgetter` might save a few more milliseconds. Perhaps also changing the logic a bit so it is not needed to calculate the same hash multiple times every iteration will help, but unless we calculate actual timings this is in the realms of premature optimization

Comment: Using `try-except` might be faster, depending on the nature of the data

Comment: Also, it may not be obvious to the OP, but putting everything inside a function so all lookups are local will definitely speed things up. Again, marginally.

Comment: Also, I wonder, does using `if ... elif` make it faster? Another obvious micro-ptimization, since we are in that realm, is to cache the attribute resolution `result_append = result.append` and use `result_append(x["whatever"])` in the loop

Comment: @DeepSpace i did used `map` and `itemgetter` as  `list(map(itemgetter('ipv4'), data))` but throws `KeyError`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could explain the "putting everything inside a function so all lookups are local will definitely speed things up" ?

Comment: @azro python global lookups require a hash lookup... literally, they check if something is in the `globals()` dict. In a function, where all the variables are local, CPython simply indexes into an array

Answer (score -2):

Try more functional style one liner:

```
ip_list = list(filter(None, map(lambda i: i.get('ipv4', i.get('ipv6')), data)))
```

Comment: Do you have some data to support the claim it is faster than OP's code?

Comment: why do you believe this will be *faster*? In general, "one-liner" does not imply "faster". But specifically, in this case,  you are never short-circuiting when you find `'ipv4'` first. Second, you are using `list(<gen exp>)` which will be slower than a list comprehension, although a list comprehension might be marginally faster than the loop. Also, you now have a list of `filter` objects... which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: For me ~73M file was processed for 8.11 seconds. It is not a "list of filter", list just converts iterable to actual list object.

Comment: In general, "one-liner" does not imply "faster" - you right but what usually faster is "functional". Functional style is faster for large datasets most of the times. Using "if statement" is slower.

Comment: You're correct, I misread this. Then if you are doing a filtering operation you should use a list comprehension, in general `filter` will be slower, even for large datasets, compared to the equivalent loop. The functional style is generally not faster in CPython